# Avoiding manually reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

It's working fine till logging into console about file change. Is it possible to update the content of text file into the browser without manually reloading the page?

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
    if(q.pathname == "/") {
    return res.end("Please request any file");      
    }
  if ( q.pathname == "/target.txt") {
    var filename = "C:\\Users\\Hp\\Documents\\Development" + q.pathname;    
  }
  else if(q.pathname == "/target1.txt") {
    var filename = "C:\\Users\\Hp\\Documents\\Development\\Node Programs\\file system module" + q.pathname;
  }
  else {
    return res.end("No such file found!");
  }
    fs.readFile(filename, function(err,data) {
    if(err) {
    return res.end("404 Not Found");
    } 
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    res.write("Now watching "+ filename);
    console.log("Now watching file");
  });

  fs.watch(filename, () => {
    fs.readFile(filename, function(err,data) {
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    res.write("Now watching "+ filename);    
    console.log("File changed");
    res.write(q.pathname+": File changed!");
    res.end();
  });
  });
  }).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/reload

> Automatically refresh and reload your code in your browser when your
>   code changes. No browser plugins required.

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping. But I am having difficulty understanding official documentation of 'reload' module. Can you please explain what is that function having three arguments and other details a bit. THANKS AGAIN IN ADVANCE.